# How to add lighting to a flat animation?

Tags: lighting, scene, 2d

Blender newbie here. I’m trying to see if Blender has a way to light imported 2d animations from the sides. What I mean by this is not darkening the image when a light source is behind it, but rather having light diffuse into the image’s edges from the side.

For example, a 2d circle moving from left to right under a static light source will have only the side closest to that light illuminated, even if it’s a flat illumination. Is there any way to do this?

Below is an example of the current object, a plane with a PNG on it. What I’d ideally go for is lighting only on the character rather than the entire plane - either rim lighting or something similar.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Maybe add some images to better illustrate the problem with an image of what you expect?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I updated the post with an example of what’s going on, though I’m not sure where to find an example of what I’m looking for. I’m not even sure if it’s possible, though I hope it is in some form.